# SQL Server: date function in group by clause

Tags: sql-server

I have one table patient and column datetime

I want datewise count of patient table
eg

```
1-1-2017  --- 10
2-1-2017 ----10
```

I am using below query but it also take time and output is like this

```
2017-02-02 11:41:13.497 --1
2017-02-02 11:36:16.823 --1
2017-02-02 10:27:47.027 --1
```

Comment: try like this GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT  CAST([datetime] AS DATE) [datetime],
        COUNT(*) AS [Result]
FROM    [patient]
GROUP BY CAST([datetime] AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CAST([datetime] AS DATE) [datetime],
        COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM    [patient]
GROUP BY CAST([datetime] AS DATE)
```